# Separar conteúdo de um RSS em duas divs

Tags: php, rss

eu tenho um código em PHP que pega o conteúdo de um feed, eu gostaria de separar esse conteúdo em duas divs.
Por exemplo: na **div1** vai estar os cinco primeiro posts em um carousel (jcarousel) e  na **div2** vai estar outros cinco posts em uma listagem.

```
<?php

            // loalidade BR e idioma pt_BR
            setlocale(LC_ALL, "pt_BR", "pt_BR.iso-8859-1", "pt_BR.utf-8", "portuguese") or die('Locale not installed');
            date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

            $rss = new DOMDocument();
            $rss->load('https://jovemnerd.com.br/nerdnews/feed/');
            $feed = array();
            foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
                $item = array ( 
                    'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                    'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                    'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                    'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                    );
                array_push($feed, $item);
            }
            <div class='box'>
            $limit = 5;

            for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
                $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
                $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
                $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
                // aqui foi alterado para a função com a formatação correta
                $date = strftime("%A, %d de %B de %Y", strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));                  
                echo '<p><strong><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></strong><br />';
                echo '<small><em>'.$date.'</em></small></p>';
                echo '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
            }?>
```

Esse é o código que eu pego os conteúdos do RSS, mas não faço a mínima ideia de como separar isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
>        $rss = new DOMDocument();
>        $rss->load('https://jovemnerd.com.br/nerdnews/feed/');
>        $feed = array();
>        foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
>            $item = array ( 
>                'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
>                'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
>                'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
>                'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
>                );
>            array_push($feed, $item);
>        }
>
>        echo '<div class="div-1">';
>            for($x=0; $x<5; $x++) {
>                $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
>                $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
>                $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
>                $date = strftime("%A, %d de %B de %Y", strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
>
>                echo '<p><strong><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></strong><br />';
>                echo '<small><em>'.$date.'</em></small></p>';
>                echo '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
>            }
>        echo '</div>';
>
>        echo '<div class="div-2">';
>            for($x=5; $x<10; $x++) {
>                $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
>                $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
>                $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
>                $date = strftime("%A, %d de %B de %Y", strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
>                echo '<p><strong><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></strong><br />';
>                echo '<small><em>'.$date.'</em></small></p>';
>                echo '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
>            }
>          echo'</div>'; ?>
> ```

Comment: Muito obrigado cara. Mas deu esse erro aqui 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/pennydreadful/public_html/teste/index.php on line 33

Comment: Troque o `<div class='div-1'>` por `echo "<div class='div-1'>"`, tem trechos de código em php e html juntos, por isso o erro. Outro opção é fechar a tag php antes do `<div class='div-1'>` e abir novamente antes do `for`

Comment: Mas aí eu não teria que mudar a estrutura de ""? pergunto isso pq não manjo de PHP.

Comment: Corrigir o código acima como foi dito pelo fernadoandrade, html estava misturado com o código do PHP.

Comment: muito obrigado @EdvaldoFarias -agora mostra esse erro: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'for' (T_FOR), expecting ',' or ';' in /home/pennydreadful/public_html/teste/index.php on line 34

Comment: O que acontece, é que ele não mostra 5 resultados por div, ele mostra muitos, olha http://www.pennydreadful.com.br/teste/

Comment: @FelipeStoker é só você limitar a quantidade da segunda `div` trocando `$x<count($feed);` por `$x<=5;` por exemplo.

Comment: A segunda DIV também terá o 5 item. eu tinha entendi que o restante das feed ficasse na segunda div.
Desculpa pelo erro.

Comment: Nota 10, muito obrigado.